# How to uninstall Kubuntu Plasma Desktop/Netbook system installed with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Unity

Tags: 12.04, unity, uninstall, kde

I installed KDE on Unity a few days ago to try. Decided to use only Unity after so I uninstalled it with Ubuntu software center. The problem is that I still have the startup and shutdown screens from KDE, and the GRUB display still has it's KDE colours. I can even access KDE normally, like before. The uninstallation didn't change a thing.

I tried using the command advised here http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/pureubuntu that was given in a similar answer on this site and i get this :

```
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Les paquets virtuels comme « kde-config-gtk-style » ne peuvent pas être supprimés
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet akonadi-facebook
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet audiocd-kio
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet colord-kde
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet kde-base-artwork
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet kde-telepathy-minimal
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet kdegames-data
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet libaudiocdplugins4
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet libkcompactdisc4
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet libkdcraw21
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet libkdecorations4abi1
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet libkdegames6
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet libkexiv2-11
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet libkipi9
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet libktorrent4
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet libktpchat0
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet libktpcommoninternalsprivate3
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet libkwineffects1abi4
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet libkwinglutils1abi1
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet libkworkspace4abi2
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet liblastfm1
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet libmailimporter4
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet libopenconnect2
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet libpoppler-qt4-4
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet libqalculate5-data
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet libtelepathy-logger-qt4-1
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet plasma-widget-telepathy-chat
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet print-manager
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet python3-pykde4
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt
```

which in english basically means that packages like `kde-config-gtk-style` can't be deleted, and beside the list of packages underneath it's said that they can't be found.

I've searched for hours and didn't find anything. I'd just like to go back exactly to how it was before i installed KDE.

Thanks!

P.S. It probably dosen't change anything but i have Windows Vista on dual boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not follow the specific instruction for your distro version.

"If you're using 12.04, [go here](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/pureubuntuprecise)"

**Source** http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/pureubuntu